# TexStudio - hyperref Warning: Values of option `pdfpagelayout'

Tags: hyperref, warnings

When compiling my Latex project using Texstudio in Windows 10 (using MiKTeX 2.9), I am getting the following warning:

```
Values of option `pdfpagelayout':(hyperref) * `SinglePage'(hyperref) * `OneColumn'(hyperref) * `TwoColumnLeft'(hyperref) * `TwoColumnRight'(hyperref) * `TwoPageLeft' (PDF 1.5)
```

The Latex code is as follows

```
%input macros (i.e. write your own macros file called MacroFile1.tex)
%\include{Macros/MacroFile1}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{pagebackref=true}{hyperref}
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{CUEDthesisPSnPDF}

%Tables and Figures
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}


%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{makeidx}  % allows for indexgeneration
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{underscore} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{draftwatermark}
%\SetWatermarkScale{4}
%\SetWatermarkLightness{0.90}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

% References
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

% ADDED PACKAGES
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    pdfpagelayout=OneColumn}


% Thickness of the border for fbox command
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.0pt}

\newcommand\abs[1]{\left|#1\right|}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=1.5pt] (char) {#1};}}

\ifpdf
    \pdfinfo { /Title  (Some Title Here)
               /Creator (TeX)
               /Producer (pdfTeX)
               /Author (Name of the author)
               /CreationDate (D:20130624000000)  %format D:YYYYMMDDhhmmss
               /ModDate (D:20140624000000)
               /Subject (Some Subject)
               /Keywords (PhD, Thesis)}
    \pdfcatalog { /PageMode (/UseOutlines)
                  /OpenAction (fitbh)  }
\fi

\title{Title of the Document}

\ifpdf
  \author{\href{mailto:some@email.com}{\textbf{Author Name}}}
  \collegeordept{\href{http://www.school.com}{School of Computing Science}}
  \university{\href{http://www.school.com}{University}}
% insert below the file name that contains the crest in-place of 'UnivShield'
   \crest{\includegraphics[width=150mm]{UnivShield}}
\else
  \author{{\bf Name}}
%  \collegeordept{School of Computing Science}
%  \university{University}
% insert below the file name that contains the crest in-place of 'UnivShield'
% \crest{\includegraphics[bb = 0 0 292 336, width=120mm]{UnivShield}}
\fi
%
% insert below the file name that contains the crest in-place of 'UnivShield'
% \crest{\IncludeGraphicsW{UnivShield}{40mm}{14 14 73 81}}
%
\renewcommand{\submittedtext}{Submitted in fulfilment of the requirements for the Degree of}
\degree{\it Doctor of Philosophy (PhD)}
\degreedate{February 2019}

\ifpdf
    \collegeordept{\href{http://www.school.com}{School of Computing Science}}
    \university{\href{http://www.school.com}{University}}
\fi

% turn of those nasty overfull and underfull hboxes
\hbadness=10000
\hfuzz=50pt

% Put all the style files you want in the directory StyleFiles and usepackage like this:
%\usepackage{StyleFiles/watermark}


\begin{document}
%\language{english}

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{0.70} % \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.2}
\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt

\newcommand\mentalnote[1]{{\color{red}#1}}

% A page with the abstract on including title and author etc may be
% required to be handed in separately. If this is not so, then comment
% the below 3 lines (between '\begin{abstractseparte}' and 
% 'end{abstractseparate}'), normally like a declaration ... needs some more
% work, mind as environment abstracts creates a new page!
% \begin{abstractseparate}
%       \input{Front/abstract}
% \end{abstractseparate}

% Using the watermark package which is in StyleFiles/
% and to remove DRAFT COPY ONLY appearing on the top of all pages comment out below line
%\watermark{DRAFT COPY ONLY}


\maketitle

%set the number of sectioning levels that get number and appear in the contents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\frontmatter
\include{Front/copyright}
\include{Front/declaration}
\include{Front/abstract}
\include{Front/acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

%\printglossary  %% Print the nomenclature
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}


\mainmatter

\part{Introduction and Background}
\label{part1}
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chapter1}
%\newpage
\input{Introduction/introduction}

\chapter{Background \texorpdfstring{\\}{} and Related Work}
\label{chapter2}
%\newpage
\input{Chapter2/Introduction}

\part{Part Name}
\label{part2}
\chapter{Chapter Name}
\label{chapter3}
%\newpage
\input{Chapter3/introduction}

\chapter{Chapter Name}
\label{chapter4}
%\newpage
\input{Chapter4/introduction}

\chapter{Chapter Name}
\label{chapter5}
%\newpage
\input{Chapter5/introduction}

\part{Part Name}
\label{part3}
\chapter{Chapter Name}
\label{chapter6}
%\newpage
\input{Chapter6/introduction}
.
.
.

\part{Conclusions}
\chapter{Conclusions and \texorpdfstring{\\}{} Future Work}
\label{chapter7}
%\newpage
\input{Chapter7/conclusion}
.
.
.    

\appendix
\include{Appendix/chapter6}
\include{Appendix/chapter6-traffic}


%\bibliographystyle{Classes/CUEDbiblio}
%\bibliographystyle{Classes/jmb}
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat} %this works with package natbib
%\bibliographystyle{Classes/jmb} % bibliography style
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography} % changes default name Bibliography to References
%\nocite{*}
\bibliography{References/citations} % References file
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} %adds References to contents page

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I tried to add the `pdfpagelayout` option in the `\hypersetup` but it is not working. Any idea of what is going on here?

**The hyperref.sty file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/rjkF8Xsm)**

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @KJO I have added the full latex code. I removed some personal information that I did not want to be online (email, name, university...). Take into account that this is the main file of a bigger project (PhD Thesis). As you can observe after \begin{document} there are few inputs of other text files. However, those files do not load any package, everything is loaded in this main file. I have also tried to load the Hyperref package just before the \begin{document} and didn't work either.

Comment: Also, I have added the hyperref.sty file in PasteBin

Comment: The latex command works fine and I am able to create a PDF out of it. However, the issue comes when I am trying to use the Convert to Html tool that comes with Texstudio. It is not working because the latex command was triggering those warnings and other errors. I managed to get rid of all the warning except this one.

Comment: Anyhow, it is a very unusual warning and couldn't find anything online to solve it. So, either way, I found useful to post the issue here for the community.

Comment: In Texstudio, go to Tools > Convert to Html (https://pasteboard.co/Ih0QDS5.jpg)

Comment: %
% CUEDthesis v1.0
% By Harish Bhanderi <harish.bhanderi@cantab.net
% Version 1.0 released 15/07/2002
%-------------------------- identification ---------------------
%\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{CUEDthesisPSnPDF}[2003/01/11 v1.2 CUED thesis class]
%-------------------------- initial code -----------------------

Comment: I just used the template that a colleague (his thesis latex code) passed me as a starting point to write my thesis. I guess he was used that old one. Do you think the problem is in the CUEDthesisPSnPDF file?

Comment: Ok. I will try to convert my thesis to use the latest version, but it will take some time to do it. If it works, I will post that as a workaround to the main issue. Many thanks for your time and help @KJO, very much appreciated.